# bound on the moment generating function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, moment-generating-functions

Let $X$ and $Y$ be discrete random variables. Is there a known class of joint distributions $p(x,y)$ which satisfies the following property:

$$\mathbb{E}\left[ e^{\lambda X} e^{\lambda Y}   \right]< \mathbb{E}\left[ e^{\lambda X}   \right]\mathbb{E}\left[  e^{\lambda Y}   \right]$$ for some $\lambda>0$?

Comment: Whenever $e^{\lambda X}$ and $e^{\lambda Y}$ are negatively correlated. This holds for example if $\lambda>0$, $X$ has nonzero variance, and $Y=-X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $X, W$ are independent, $X$ has nonzero variance, and $Y=W-X$. Then 
$$ E[e^{\lambda X} e^{\lambda Y}] < E[e^{\lambda X}] E[e^{\lambda Y}] \quad \forall \lambda >0$$
This is because (by Jensen's inequality) :
\begin{align}
E[e^{\lambda X}] &> e^{\lambda E[X]}\\
E[e^{\lambda Y}] &= E[e^{\lambda W}]E[e^{-\lambda X}] > E[e^{\lambda W}]e^{-\lambda E[X]}
\end{align}
and so (since the right-hand-sides of the above inequalities are positive):
$$ E[e^{\lambda X}]E[e^{\lambda Y}] > E[e^{\lambda W}] = E[e^{\lambda (X+Y)}]$$

Comment: Here I am implicitly assuming that all expectations used are finite.

Comment: ok, I think the above is true! Assume that for a set $\{ Z_i :i\in[n] \}$ there exist $W_i$ such that $Z_i=W_i -\sum^{i-1}_{j=1} Z_i$ and $W_i$, $\sum^{i-1}_{j=1} Z_i$  are independent. Can we apply your answer recursively to get $\mathbb{E}\left[ \prod^{n}_{i=1} e^{\lambda z_i}
 \right]<\prod^{n}_{i=1}\mathbb{E}\left[ e^{\lambda z_i}  \right] $

Comment: Yes, if we fix $i\geq 2$ it looks like we take $X=\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}Z_j$, $W=W_i$, $Y=W-X$ to get $$\underbrace{E[e^{\lambda (X+Y)}]}_{E\left[e^{\lambda \sum_{j=1}^iZ_j}\right]} < \underbrace{E[e^{\lambda X}]}_{E\left[e^{\lambda\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}Z_j}\right]}\underbrace{E[e^{\lambda Y}]}_{E[e^{\lambda Z_i}]}$$ assuming $X$ has nonzero variance.  And by recursion the inequality unravels.